# How to make a tableView recognize phone numbers and email addresses in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm making an app for a company that has 7 branches.  I wanted to make a contact list that is in a grouped view, divided by branches.  Is there any way to make the table view recognize phone numbers/email address from my plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) and set the `dataDetectorTypes` property. You can use the data detector UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber for the numbers. The email address you will probably have to come up with something custom.

Comment: I could set it up the way you mentioned but using a table view would organize it a lot nicer.  As I say, there are 7 branches with 2 sets of phone numbers and at least one email for each.  Guess I'll just have to come up with something using the scroll view.  Thanks anyways.